# Is it possible to show the exact position in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, markdown

I've been learning Markdown, and using the Python Markdown package, which often returns the following when I try to convert text that has been pasted in from the web:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in 
position 1611: ordinal not in range(128)
```

At the bottom of my editor I currently see this:

```
COMMAND MODE, Line X, Column Y
```

Is there a setting in Sublime Text 2 that will show the full position (as in `1611` in the example above) at all times so I can quickly find the bad character?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could make a simple python script to do this.

1.
Save this code to your User folder as `characterCounter.py` (`Preferences > Browse Packages > User`):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class PositionListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
  def on_selection_modified(self,view):
    text = "Position: "
    sels = view.sel()
    for s in sels:
        text += " " + str(s.begin())
        if not s.empty():
            text += "-" + str(s.end()) + " "
    view.set_status('exact_pos', text)
```

2.
Then restart Sublime Text to have it loaded.

Comment: Thank you for code. I made little fix. When you use many cursors without selecting anything there is no space: http://hastebin.com/cejosemeka.py

Comment: Stupid question: how do you enable it? I have saved the script but Sublime doesn't seem to know it's there. Thanks.

Comment: @gotofritz You can see "Position: 123" in the lower left of SublimeText if you copy this script into a .py file and save it to the folder opened by Preferences > Browse Packages > User

Comment: I believe that Sublime doesn't have to be restarted - it detects the change and loads the plugin automatically.

Comment: I was having a similar problem in some mako templates were I had made the mistake of pasting from a google doc straight into my source. This script worked but didn't solve my problem because the offending characters weren't displayable. I wound up solving the problem by loading the file into the hex editor HxD and deleting the  characters at the positions specified in the errors that I was getting.

Comment: Very nice! With sublime 3 had to restart sublime to make it work

Comment: Curious how to enable jumping to character position (Ctrl + G) without digging up too much sublime api..

Comment: @matanster - this should be a new question

Comment: This is helpful, but seems to count `\r\n` as a single character